# MediaElemnt.js in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

MediaElement.js version 2.15.1

Chrome Version version 37.0.2062.102 m

When streaming chunked mp3 audio, all browsers work except Chrome.  Chrome throws the following error from within mediaElement.js:

```
net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

Request/Resonse Headers are as follows:

```
// Request Headers ========================
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=74155917.349885350.1406820465.1400689847.1409751290.19; __utmb=74155917.7.10.1409752290; __utmc=74155917; __utmz=74155917.1402820465.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=sj8mcfcq8qevfi1cks2cke3vr1
Host:www.thesite.com
Pragma:no-cache
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:https://thesite.com/listen.php?id=647
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.102 Safari/537.36

// Response Headers =======================
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:
Connection:close
Content-Disposition:inline; filename=/var/www/thesite.com/www/mp3/20/xjy7q4ew7d9vq7i-09-Stereogenosis_etc.mp3
Content-Length:3592068
Content-Range:bytes 0-3592067/3592068
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Date:Wed, 03 Sep 2014 14:17:09 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 23 Mar 2012 19:13:21 -0400
Pragma:
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=sj8mcfcq8qevfi1cks9cke3vr5; path=/
```

I have checked server-side, and it seems the entire file is being delivered on the first request, but Chrome is not aware of this, attempts to request an additional range, and finds the connection closed.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: what is your MEJS initialization code? I have had some issues with chrome while loading media dynamically via ajax and solved them calling `mediaElement.load()` inside the `success` setting of the MEJS initialization before attempting to play the media. It seems that webkit browsers fire some methods before the player is completely ready so most likely you might be experiencing the same issue with Safari too.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  The error ended up being server side (off-by-one) which, apparently, IE, Safari, and Firefox didn't care about.